# How to control output files in Random Vibration simulation for system level simulations in ANSYS

Tags: ansys

I am working on ECU Random vibration simulation in Ansys Mechanical. In order to compute statistical output from Random excitation, Ansys needs all nodal results such as displacements, accelerations, velocities in its Modal results for subsequent PSD analysis. This is increasing my *.rst file size as I have too many modes in my modal space. How can I control my output file size in such simulation so that I have to deal with fewer file size while post processing.

Many thanks for your help.

My expectation is that output file should be under 10GB.